# How to position a SVG arrow next to a button

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Essentially, I want to accomplish this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Sfq.png)

I have figured out that I can set `z-index` to `1000` and use `position: absolute`, however I can't figure out to what to set the `top` and `left` properties because the position of the button changes depending on the content.

Comment: It would be better if you'd include your code

Comment: there's no way including a massive PHP file will help. The arrow is a SVG, everything else is regular HTML with Bootstrap 3 markup. Essentially the question is, how to position an absolute `<div>`, next to a given element on the page.

Comment: What i mean was, how do you expect anybody to guess how your html is structured then help you solve your problem, you're saying an SVG img, yes then what SVG img is that all we see is you talking about the problem but no problem, i didn't say include everything, just a snippet that shows the problem

Comment: people are trying to help you. don't be rude.
You can create a Minimal Reproducible Example Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing SVG arrow as `::after` of the `<button>`. Position `<button>` relatively and `::after` absolutely.

```
button {
  position: relative;
}

button::after {
  position: absolute;
}
```

This way you will be able to make `::after` always relative to the `<button>` using standard `left` and `top` properties

Comment: cool idea, but when the SVG image goes outside of the bounding box of the button element, it gets cut out like this star [here](https://i.imgur.com/7lYhtxi.png). `z-index` does not appear to do anything, neither does `overflow: visible`

Comment: aaaaaand that's specifically why you should share something more than just a question - pieces of code or background information. You mention bootstrap in the comment. My solution will of course work. But not in your custom and specific situation.

Comment: your solution worked! I had to create a container element and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> how to position an absolute `<div>`, next to a given element on the page

better to have parent child relationship between the two

## DEMO

Say the `:before` is the svg img

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

button>div {
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
  width: 30%;
  height: 2px;
  left: 105%;
  top: 50%;
}


/* Irelevent : just for demonstration */
button>div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -9px;
  right: calc(100% - 22px);
}
button>div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    bottom: calc(100% - 2px);
    left: 50% ;
    border-top:none;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me <div></div></button>
```

when an element is relatively positioned all of it's absolute/relative positioned
children will be relative to it, so when you say `left:100%` on a child, it will push at child to 100% of the parent width, which makes it easy to position an element relative to another. from here you just need to disable all the inherited styling if you don't know what i mean try clicking the button.